# Injecting data or html into app.component

Tags: angular

I am making my first Angular application (Angular 6), and in the app component I have sidebar, navigation and breadcrumb. When a component is loaded I want to load the breadcrumb values from the child component. I can see if you want to send data to the app.component you use an Output and emit pattern. Is this the correct approach for this kind of scenarios, or what is the best approach? All inputs are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn a bit about the Router, RouteSnapshot and ActivatedRoute.
This can help you get the parent/child relationships to create dynamic breadcrumbs, otherwise you'll end up using static data passed between components. 
You should create a "breadcrumb" component and listen to the routeSnapshot, this could be a starting point.

check the docs 
https://angular.io/guide/router